# Which distribution to use for a probability problem?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

> In a food processing plant, on average, 2 packaging machines breakdown per week.

I let x be the number of processing machine breakdowns in a week. So x is Poisson(2), but one part of the question says:

> in a random sample of 26 machines what is the probability of no machine breakdowns in at least one of them in a week.

I know, mean = 2 and solve 2=26*p to get p=1/13. Then I say x is Binomial(26, 1/13).

But now I do not know where to go from there. Any suggestions please? I am not interested in the final answer, I just need to be pointed on the right track from where I am.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thank you. Is the assumption behind this question that a machine can break down once per week or not at all? (Ie, can it keep breaking down every 20 min?)

Comment: I'm assuming that a machine can only break down once per week

Comment: In that case, each machine can break down or not. You can have 0 breakdowns, 1, 2, ..., 26. What distribution is that?

Comment: Binomial I get that. Then in that case I figure the answer  should be P(x=<25) i.e. At most 25 machines cam break down. Sound right?

Comment: From the 2nd part of the question, it sounds like they want to know the probability that 0 machines will break down. $P(0|{\rm binom}(26, 1/13))\ne P(X\le25|{\rm binom}(26, 1/13)$

Comment: No, what is the probability that at least one machine doesn't breakdown. But 2, 3 or more could not breakdiwn

Comment: There is a contradiction between that phrasing ("the probability that at least one machine doesn't breakdown") & what is in your Q ("the probability of no machine breakdowns"). Which correctly matches the question you were asked?

Comment: Probability of no breakdowns in one of the machines. Could my assumption that a machine can only break down once per week be wrong?

Comment: I think your assumption about machines breaking down once per week is likely right. I think there is some ambiguity here about the number of breakdowns you are being asked about.

Comment: Either way, if you believe the relevant probability distribution is binom(26, 1/13), you should be able to calculate the probability for either of the two options.

Comment: If you don't think P(x=<25) is right then I have no idea. Only thing that makes sense to me

Comment: From the phrasing in the Q above, it would be P(x=0). But you can calculate both of those probabilities, now that you have a candidate distribution that you think is the right one [viz, binom(26, 1/13)].

Comment: P(x=0) would be none of the 26 machines breakdown. But the question is at least one machine doesn't breakdown

Comment: Right. But P(x=0) matches the phrasing in your Q above ("the probability of no machine breakdowns"). I don't know which accurately matches the question you were asked, but I do have a sense of how such questions are typically asked & P(x=0) would be much more common. It doesn't matter though. Go w/ P(x<=25), if you like. You should be able to calculate either probability now.

Comment: **This question lacks the information needed to be answerable.** To see why, consider two extreme cases. (1) There are a huge number of machines.  The fact that on average only two break down per week means the chance of any individual breakdown is extremely low, whence the chance of no breakdown in 26 machines is high.  (2) There are exactly 26 machines. The chance of no breakdown, according to the Poisson distribution, is $e^{-2}\approx 13\%$, which is not high.  Obviously, then, **the answer depends on how many machines there are,** which you do not know.

Answer (score 5):

The following analysis illustrates one approach to obtaining a solution.  At least it might help show how to work with the Poisson distribution.

To answer this question constructively and clearly, let's make a few simplifying assumptions to avoid getting bogged down in details that haven't been described.  For instance, you might choose to

- assume that a "breakdown" is an event with such a short duration that a machine is back in operation immediately after a breakdown; and
- therefore the same machine could break down multiple times during a week (although this might be a rare event).

As apparently intended by the question, we will make some additional stronger assumptions.  Some such (modeling) assumptions are needed to make any progress at all with the answer.  Their chief purpose would be to give us a point of departure for eliciting additional information from the plant engineers so we could develop improved models and better answers:

- All machines independently have the same chances of breaking down and
- those chances do not vary over time.

These assumptions imply the number of breakdowns observed among any number $N$ of machines during any period of $x$ weeks has a Poisson$(\lambda N x)$ distribution, where $\lambda$ is a parameter common to all machines at all times.  The question tells us about the breakdown rate for $x = 1$ week:

$$\lambda N 1\text{ weeks} = 2.$$

Therefore

$$\lambda = 2 / (N \text{ machine-weeks}).$$

In a random sample of $26$ such machines, the number of breakdowns in a week will have a Poisson distribution with parameter

$$\mu = \lambda\times (26\text{ machines})\times (1\text{ week}) = 26\lambda = 52/N.$$

From the formula for Poisson probabilities, **the chance of no breakdowns among these $26$ machines** is

$$e^{-\mu} 0! = e^{-\mu} = e^{-26\lambda} = e^{-52/N}.$$

Since $N\ge 26$, this value cannot exceed $e^{-52/26}=e^{-2}\approx 0.135$, but as $N$ grows large it could become arbitrarily small.

**This is not a final answer.** It only shows the implication of four assumptions that were made upon interpreting the question in terms of the chance of no breakdowns in a week.  (Other interpretations of the question are possible, due to the contorted syntax used to pose it.)  In particular, the dependence upon the unknown total number of machines is clear and explicit.  This is about as far as one can go, given the limited information supplied in the question.

---

A simulation (covering almost 200 years of operation) illustrates the ideas.  Its output consists of two histograms: the weekly breakdown counts for all $N$ machines and the counts for the sample of the machines.  Here is an example for $N=60$:

[image: Figure]

On each histogram are drawn two vertical lines: a gray one indicating the location of the actual rate (as given by the preceding solution) and a dashed red one indicating the average rate during the simulation.  In each case those lines are visibly coincident, showing that the simulation and the preceding analysis are in agreement.

Studying the `R` code that produced this simulation may help clarify the ideas.

```r
n <- 60           # Number of machines
sample.size <- 26 # Must be less than or equal to n
weekly.mean <- 2  # Events per week, on average
n.iter <- 1e4     # Size of this simulation in weeks
set.seed(17)      # Reproduce these results exactly
#
# Simulate all machines.
#
lambda <- weekly.mean/n                          # Weekly breakdown rate per machine
x <- matrix(rpois(n.iter*n, lambda), nrow=n)     # Breakdowns by machine by week
weekly.breakdowns <- colSums(x)                  # Total breakdowns each week
sample.breakdowns <- colSums(x[1:sample.size, ]) # Total breakdowns in the sample
#
# Plot the results.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
eps <- 0.99
hist(weekly.breakdowns, breaks=(-1):max(weekly.breakdowns)+eps,
     freq=FALSE, cex.main=0.9)
abline(v=lambda * n, lwd=2, col="Gray")
abline(v=mean(weekly.breakdowns), col="Red", lwd=3, lty=3)

mu <- weekly.mean * sample.size / n
hist(sample.breakdowns, breaks=(-1):max(sample.breakdowns)+eps,
     freq=FALSE, cex.main=0.9)
abline(v=mu * n, lwd=2, col="Gray")
abline(v=mean(sample.breakdowns), col="Red", lwd=3, lty=3)
```

Comment: +1, did you interpret the original HW question to be about Poisson instead of binomial, or did you just want to offer a contrasting possibility?

Comment: @gung I interpreted it from the outset as fishing for a Poisson assumption (as recognized by the OP); everything else followed from that.  The answer can also be obtained from a Binomial analysis of the 26 machines, or even a perfectly elementary calculation, all of which agree with the Poisson result: Pr(no breakdowns) = Pr(no breakdowns in machine 1) * Pr(none in machine 2) * ... * Pr(none in machine 26) = $(e^{-2/N})^{26} = e^{-52/N}$.

Answer (score 4):

Both the Poisson and the binomial distribution can model counts, but they do so differently.  You assume that each machine can break down or not at most once each week.  That suggests a particular distribution is more appropriate.

From this, and your calculations, you believe the right distribution is binom(26, 1/13).  You should be able to calculate probabilities directly from that distribution, now that you have settled on one.

The probability you are asked to calculate is somewhat ambiguous.  The phrasing in the body of the question ("the probability of no machine breakdowns") is inconsistent with what you report in the comments ("the probability that at least one machine doesn't breakdown").  These two would be $P(X=0|{\rm binom}(26, 1/13))$ and $P(X\le25|{\rm binom}(26, 1/13)$, respectively, which are not equal.  Irregardless of which is what you were asked, both should be straightforward to calculate from the distribution you have decided on.